# top says iwlwifi's pr is -51

Tags: process-priority

My understanding is that the pr value is the nice +20. So how can a process have a pr value less than 0?

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
619 root     -51   0     0    0    0 S   3.6  0.0   5:37.44 [irq/46-iwlwifi]
```

Comment: Presumably, because it has happened here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PR** here is the value of the **real-time priority**, you can check its value for `irq/47-iwlwifi` with the `ps` command:

```
$ ps -eo pid,rtprio,ni,pri,comm 
  PID RTPRIO  NI PRI COMMAND
[...]
  497     50   -  90 irq/47-iwlwifi
```

[Source](http://atipaday.wordpress.com/2008/08/19/atad-21-linux-process-priority-range/).

Comment: Thanks, top was telling me it was a negative value, and when I did the research I was informed that the value was in the range 0 to 99, so I just wasn't sure.